# Angular rxjs-interval operator (polling) redraws component view every time data is fetched

Tags: angular, rxjs6

My component fetches data from a service in the following way:

```
ngOnInit() {
    interval(5000)
    .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        switchMap(() => this.rawMaterialDataService.returnData())
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.rawMaterialProductData = data;
    });
}
```

It then renders it into another component like so:

```
<section *ngFor='let stock of rawMaterialProductData trackBy:stock?.key'>
    <app-raw-material-view [stockGroupData]='stock'></app-raw-material-view>
</section>
```

The problem is that every time the data is re-fetched, the child component gets re-rendered, but not the parent component. I have put a console.log in the Init method of the child component, and every 5 seconds the log message gets triggered, meaning that the Init got run.

So the problem with this is that my child component has drop-down templates, that the user looks at, but every time the component re-renders the templates close back up to their initial state.

As you can see I tried `trackBy` to solve this issue, but it did not help.

-- Edit --

Here is the component that the data gets used in

```
<table (click)=collaps()>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id='th1'>{{stockGroupData.key}}</th>
            <div class="topnav-right">
                <th *ngIf="!expandedIndex" class='headingIcon'> <i class="material-icons">expand_more</i></th>
                <th *ngIf="expandedIndex" class='headingIcon'> <i class="material-icons">expand_less</i></th>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngIf="!expandedIndex">
        Test
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please post how are you using your components in template?

Comment: I have added my child component template as well.

Comment: I meant the template where you have used your parent and child component selectors. How are you passing the data?

Comment: That would be my second code block, as you can see `rawMaterialProductData` is the data that I fetch, and then in my template I pass that data to child component `app-raw-material-view`. The third code block is the template of the child component.

Comment: There may not be a way to get past this - cause every time "new" data is fetched, the `*ngFor` loop would have to run to process the data, and that would mean re-drawing the child templates...  :(

Comment: I am just curious, is `trackBy:stock?.key` syntax supported? As I see in fresh documentation the trackBy directive expects a function. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby

Comment: You can store the state of your drop down in a service.. which you can inject in your component and when the components re-renders use the drop down state from the service.

Comment: @Nikolai Thank you for bringing my intention to this fact. I have never implemented the `trackBy` correctly (the example was not very instructive that I found) and after playing around with it, it seems to work now. I would like to know however, is it possible to use `trackBy` more than one level deep (array in an array)?